# nyc (istanbul) doesn't work when NODE_ENV is set to test

Tags: reactjs, mocha.js, istanbul, nyc

I'm performing mocha tests on my React components that I wrote using ES6 syntax. I'm using Istanbul to do code coverage tests. When i set my `NODE_ENV` to 'test`, I get the following output:

```
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines |Uncovered Lines |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------------|
All files |  Unknown |  Unknown |  Unknown |  Unknown |                |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------------|
```

As can be seen, it says unknown for everything. When I remove the `NODE_ENV` variable, it works fine. What can I do to run this test in the above environment?

Answer (score 3):

I have been trying the last two days to set up a similar environment using babel, nyc and react and faced similar problems.
How are you setting the NODE_ENV? Are you on Windows?

This is what I had in my package.json:

```
"test:c": "set NODE_ENV=test && npm run coverage"
```

When this is executed, windows actually sets the NODE_ENV as "test " not as "test".
Notice the trailing whitespace.

I fixed this by removing the space from the script :

```
"test:c": "set NODE_ENV=test&& npm run coverage"
```

Comment: I used the npm package called `cross-env`. So my test script is
`"test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test nyc mocha"`
And yes, I'm on Windows.

Comment: well it seems like you could have the same issue, in your case NODE_ENV could be interpreted as 'test ', with a whitespace

Try splitting the script in two scripts like this:

     `"test" :  "cross-env NODE_ENV=test&&npm run actual_test",

     "actual_test" : "nyc mocha"`

That way NODE_ENV should be set correctly

Answer (score 0):

Use `cross-env` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env)

In `package.json`:

`"test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test nyc mocha --exit && npm run coverage"`